# table size problem

Tags: html

sir when i insert a long string data the table size comes out of the page as show below.

[http://lh3.ggpht.com/_Um0yFxPtzJ8/S0G8dGp1EcI/AAAAAAAAACc/JOJGrM0U-dI/s800/untitled.JPG http://lh3.ggpht.com/_Um0yFxPtzJ8/S0G8dGp1EcI/AAAAAAAAACc/JOJGrM0U-dI/s800/untitled.JPG](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_Um0yFxPtzJ8/S0G8dGp1EcI/AAAAAAAAACc/JOJGrM0U-dI/s800/untitled.JPG)

should i userd table-layout:fixed;word-wrap:break-word; 
as:

table { border-width:1 px; background-color: #ffffff; border-right-color: #828DAF; border-bottom-color: #828DAF; border-top-color:#828DAF; border-left-color: #828DAF; table-layout:fixed; word-wrap:break-word; }

but its nt working???

Comment: Yes, it does. Wide content needs space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tommy said, you want to use "table-layout: fixed" in the CSS for your table.

Then you have at least three choices for what to do with table cells that have too much content:

1. Do nothing - they'll keep going outside their cell.
2. word-wrap:break-word will break in the middle of a word
3. overflow:hidden (on the TD, not the TABLE) will cause the rest of the text to be hidden; the user can expose more by making the window wider or decreasing the font size.

Answer (score 4):

try this css

table-layout:fixed;word-wrap:break-word;

Comment: should i write it here?


table {

 border-width:1 px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 border-right-color: #828DAF;
 border-bottom-color: #828DAF;
 border-top-color:#828DAF;
 border-left-color: #828DAF;
 table-layout:fixed;
 word-wrap:break-word;
}


coz its nt working???

Comment: table-layout belongs to table
word-wrap:break-word;overflow:hidden; belongs to the td or any wrapper u put into the table cell.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to reduce your font size or add a `div` around your `table` and add `overflow: auto;` to it ... so an horizontal scroll bar appears when you have too much content in your table.